# Create an individual integer for each ArrayList element?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, arraylist

I'm developing some kind of "score tracker" app for a certain game. A user adds a certain amount of players (the number is currently unlimited) and those player names are then added to ArrayList. Then on the next activity, the user must choose a playername from a Spinner and enter a certain amount of "points" or let's say "score" for that player.

This is my current code for this:

```
public void submitScore(View v){
    LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.linearLayout);
    final int position = playerList.getSelectedItemPosition();
    EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    final LinearLayout.LayoutParams lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final TextView newTextView = new TextView(this);
    String enteredText = input.getText().toString();
    
    if (enteredText.matches(""))
    {
        emptyTextError();
    }
    else
    {
        //NEW TEXTVIEW
        newTextView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        newTextView.setText(players.get(position) + " " + score);
        newTextView.setTextSize(20);
        lLayout.addView(newTextView);
    }
}
```

As you can see, a user enters a certain score and a new textview is created containing player name and current score.

Now what I want to do is implement a feature that will track score for each player.

Example: The user added 2 players, one named John and one named Jack. The user then added 20 points to John and then after a while another 20, also to john. Now the textViews should look like this:

> John 20
>
> John 40

And then if the user will add 10 points to Jack and another 20 to John, TextViews should look like this:

> John 20
>
> John 40
>
> Jack 10
>
> John 60

This is what I don't know what to do. How do I implement a new int variable for each ArrayList element? Or is there a better way to do this than making int variables?

I need the app to automatically generate ints accoring to ArrayList, if the ArrayList contains 5 players, 5 ints need to be created because I don't know how many players the user will enter.

Comment: Why not use a _Map_ or a _List_ of _<Player,score> compositions_?

Comment: @rocketboy I've never done anything like that, I'm still a beginner. Could you add some explanation on how to do this? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a class, perhaps called 'Player'. Each player will have a String value `name` and an int value `score`. Then you can add these `Player` instances to the array each time a new Player is created. See how to do it in the [Java class toturial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try and let you know how it goes

Comment: Also, OP should learn about `Map`s and other collections at [the Collections tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections)

Answer (score 0):

```
     class PlayerScore{

         String userName;
         int score;
         public PlayerScore(String userName, int score) {
                    this.userName = userName;
                    this.score = score;
         }

       //setter and getter

      }    

       List<PlayerScore> playerScore=new ArrayList<PlayerScore>();
       playerScore.add(new PlayerScore("John",20));
       playerScore.add(new PlayerScore("John",40));
       playerScore.add(new PlayerScore("Jack",10));
       playerScore.add(new PlayerScore("John",60));
```

Comment: this is not what Matthew meant. He adds 2x20 which is 40. You are adding 40 directly. So there needs to be some audit/history property for the scores in the player object.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `Map<String,Integer>`, for faster access try `HashMap<~>`

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("John", 10);
    map.put("Bob", 40);
```

If you want to sort by name use a TreeMap. If you want to sort by score read this old thread:
[Sort a Map<Key, Value> by values (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)